# PHP Cron job process with marker in URL

Tags: php, curl, cron

I want to process a script every minute using a cron on my server but I need to pass a variable in the URL or some other way. I have researched this and I've seen solutions using arguments in the cron but I don't think that works with what I'm doing.

Here is what I am trying to do:

script.php (runs every minute)

```
<?php

$marker = $_GET['marker'];

$accountObj = new etAccounts($consumer);

    $request_params = new TransactionHistoryRequest();
    $request_params->__set('count', 50); //how many will be shown
    if($marker_get != ''){
    $request_params->__set('marker', $marker_get); //starting point ex. 14293200140265
    }
        $json = $accountObj->GetTransactionHistory($account, $request_obj, $request_params );
echo $json; //shows most recent 50 transactions starting from marker value

//process json data here...
//included in json is a marker variable that will be used to return the next 50 json results
//after data is processed reload the page with marker in URL

header('Location: script.php?marker=14293200140265');

?>
```

I understand that cron is CLI on the server side and that it can't process redirections or header locations but how is this possible. I saw someone mention using CURL, how might this work? Example?

Comment: Are you calling the same script at the end of the script? That will lead to an infinite loop. Until your server resources run out...

Comment: you are correct, I have a exit(); in the loop with an if statement, so yes it loops about 3 times and then stops.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are trying to do. You can add parameters to the command line and if you want your script to loop 3 times, just use a loop, there is no need for a redirect. And sending the server admin 3 mails a minute (that's all that `echo` does here...) with lists of 50 results, is not going to make anybody happy.

Comment: the first time the script is called, $marker is empty, then there is a marker included in the first json data, then I would reload the page with that marker in the URL which then passes that variable back to the function and displays a new set of 50 results with a new marker variable and then the process repeats until no more results left. If I run it in a browser it works perfectly but does not on cron, that's why I'm trying to find a solution

Comment: But can't you wrap everything in a loop then? Something like: `do { ... } while (!empty($your_marker_variable));`?

Comment: I think so. How would that script look?

Answer (score 0):

Simple example to send post variables to an url:

```
$fields = array(
    'id' => $id, 
    'mail' => $mail, 
);

$url = "yourdomain.com"; 
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments, you don't need to redirect or use query variables.

You could use a loop that runs while your `marker` variable is not empty:

```
$your_marker_variable = '';
do {

    $accountObj = new etAccounts($consumer);

    $request_params = new TransactionHistoryRequest();
    $request_params->__set('count', 50); //how many will be shown
    if($marker_get != '') {
      $request_params->__set('marker', $marker_get); //starting point ex. 14293200140265
    }
    $json = $accountObj->GetTransactionHistory($account, $request_obj, $request_params );
    echo $json; //shows most recent 50 transactions starting from marker value

    //process json data here...
    //included in json is a marker variable that will be used to return the next 50 json results

    // set the new value of $your_marker_variable
    $your_marker_variable = ...
} while (!empty($your_marker_variable));
```

Note that the undefined and unused variables in the script you posted, make it hard to see what variable is used for what, so you would need to adapt this a bit.